# Drupal Version Control settings

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to configure git for drupal on windows 7. I had added a git repo to my wamp/www file, but it was not detecting changes that I had made on a localhost test server. I checked the ignore file and started following the directions here https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/31578

Getting stuck at step 2, number 4, (Set "Git binary path").

[image: setting git binary path]

I then tried in environment variables in system properties to augment the system variables path with the following lines.
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

I ran git version from both git bash and the command promp and there were no errors which seemed to me like the git path was correct.

I also tried to manually set the path in version control settings but its not working. I've read similar posts to this one before posting and i'm still suck. Thanks from a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the full path to the actual git binary. In my case this is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```